# Should localstorage be set from within react callbacks?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In a (typescript) react app, I have some hooks for reading and writing to local storage, like this:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

...

export const useLocalStorage = (key, defaultValue) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
        return getStorageValue(key, defaultValue);
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }, [key, value]);

    return [value, setValue];
};
```

Elsewhere in the app, I have a UX element that needs to store some data in local storage, as part of an `onClick()` callback:

```js
myValue, setMyValue = useLocalStorage("MY_KEY", 0);
...

    onClick() => {
        setMyValue("some data");
    }
```

However, this means calling `useEffect()` from within a callback, which violates the [hook rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Is it conventional here to just call `localstorage.setItem()` directly from withing the callback, or is there a more idiomatic way to refactor this code?

Comment: The useEffect will not be called in the callback, you'll just call set value, and since the value change it'll trigger the useEffect inside your hook in the next render so everything is fine

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a little confused about what a hook is. Consider this snipet.

```
function Button() {
  const [wasClicked, setWasClicked] = useState(false);
  
  function handleClick() {
    setWasClicked(true) // completely legal.
    // this is not "calling a hook"

    const [clickedTime, setClickedTime] = useState(Date.now()) // illegal
    // this is "calling a hook"
  }

  return <button disabled={wasClicked} onclick={handleClick}>click!</button>
}
```

Calling a hook like `useState(false)` is as you say not permitted within callbacks. This is because the order in which hooks are called is actually super important to React. So, you can't conditionally call hooks, and you cant call them from a callback, you have to call them at the top level of your component.

That being said, `setWasClicked` is **not** a hook, it's just a regular function that happens to be returned from a hook. You can call this function from anywhere, because as stated it is not a hook.

In your case, `useLocalStorage` is a hook, you have to follow the rules of hooks. However, it returns `setValue` which is not a hook, just a regular function returned by the `useState` call. That triggers the useEffect callback to run, but it doesn't re-run useEffect. useEffect was called only when you called `useLocalStorage`.

TLDR:
To answer your question, I would put local storage stuff in a hook. You do want to use the `useEffect` hook because you don't want to access localStorage on every render, only when dependencies change.